# How to verify a £ symbol in Selenium IDE?

Tags: testing, selenium, currency, selenium-ide, verify

So trying to get to grips with selenium, and for my first test case I'm trying to write a test case to ensure stock feeds have loaded. Therefore I want to verify that there are page numbers, and that there are £ signs.

Pagination seems to work ok, but I can not get it to pick up the £ sign.

Here's what I got:

```
open                    -The page in question-
verifyElementPresent    css=div.result_count     result_count
verifyText              id=boxed-container       £
```

I'm sure there must be something simple I'm missing. Any helps appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Please share a relevant part of your HTML code.

I've encountered similar problem with text inside an input maybe it's your case

`VerifyText` checks for the text inside a html node.

However as `<input />` is a single tag and its value is stored in the `value` attribute you must use `VerifyValue` instead

**EDIT**

Use `verifyText` and target: `xpath=//*[contains(text(),'£')]`

Comment: <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4 no-gutter">
<div class="row">
<span class="pull-right text-right"><strong>£9,995</strong></span>
</div> 
</div>

(sorry about appearance, not sure how to tell stack that this is code in the comments)

Hope this helps. 

I did just try verifyValue instead but no luck :/

Comment: You can write code with text between two of this little symbol --> `  
I've editted my answer

Comment: Thx for your help! Unfortunately this appears not to work either. Should I have put anything in the value field as well? (I tried with and without '£' sign)

Comment: I tried on Selenium IDE and indeed it raises weird errors. It finds a paragraph but cannot isolate the word I'm looking for. You should consider moving to Selenium webdriver once you're a little more familiar with Selenium because the IDE is very limited.